# SP2013 Workflow Suspend

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am facing issue with work flow where Workflow goes to Suspend mode.
It is SP2013 Custom Workflow developed using Visual Studio 2012.Objective of the Custom workflow: User fills the form and submit, list get updated and workflow will initiate and go for the process.

**Issue:** After the deployment of WF, for first time when user is filling the form and submit, list is getting updated. But the Workflow Goes to "Suspend" mode. (
This Custom Workflow has a configuration file where we are providing other details including ID of Impersonator (farm is running under Claim Based Authentication).

Work flow works fine once when the Impersonator initiate the workflow (Fill the form and submit for approval) and everything works fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the information icon next to the Suspended status. The error message should be listed there. If it is sitting in a suspended state saying Activity in Progress, this is usually an issue with the certificate chain between SharePoint and the Workflow Server.